# Cos'è un "macello gentile"?

Tags: meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Non eravamo gli ultimi della nostra parentela e se la facevano tutti abbastanza bene: chi aveva la censa, chi il **macello gentile**, chi un bel pezzo di terra propria.

Potreste spiegarmi cos'è o era un "mecello  gentile"? Ho cercato alle voci "macello" e "gentile" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato questa espressione né nessuna accezione di "gentile" che mi sembri adeguata a qualificare una macelleria o mattatoio. Una ricerca su Google però mi ha fatto vedere che si tratta di un'espressione abbastanza usata.  Ho visto persino qualche fotografia che mostra una porta con un cartello con la scritta "macello gentile" sopra.

Comment: La prima cosa che mi viene in mente è il macello per i non-ebrei (i *gentili*), quindi non *kosher*. Però non mi risulta che Fenoglio fosse ebreo, per cui questa supposizione sembra quantomeno tirata per i capelli

Comment: Secondo [questo documento di Edizioni Atlas](https://www.edatlas.it/documents/1f315a6f-f4dd-4e39-b59b-b01a40eefd5b), che propone un lavoro scolastico su un frammento del romanzo *La malora*, si tratta di un locale "in cui si macellano carni di categoria superiore".

Comment: Ah, quindi sarebbe più o meno l'opposto della [bassa macelleria](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/macelleria).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oltre al [documento](https://www.edatlas.it/documents/1f315a6f-f4dd-4e39-b59b-b01a40eefd5b) già menzionato da Charo nei commenti, sono riuscito a scovare un [atto di governo del 1812 del regno di Sardegna](https://books.google.fr/books?id=SXcrAQAAMAAJ&lpg=PA452&ots=QHcOjarflv&dq=%22macello%20gentile%22&pg=PA119#v=onepage&q&f=false) che può dare luce sulla situazione.

> Fra queste [vecchie leggi] abbiamo ravvisato quella [...] di permettere ai macellai di vitelli di poter anche smerciare un sesto di moggie al prezzo medesimo della carne di vitello [...] allo scopo di non lasciar di troppo elevare il prezzo della carne di vitello con aggravio dei compratori, poiché nel formare il prezzo medio della **carne gentile**, su cui si stabiliva la tassa, si faceva entrare per un terzo circa il valore della carne di moggia, accomunata come carne di terza qualità con quella di prima e seconda di vitello.

Non sono riuscito a scoprire cosa sia la carne di moggia, ma è chiaro dal contesto che si tratta di carne di qualità inferiore alla carne di vitello. Questo suggerisce di cercare l'espressione *vitello gentile* e, in effetti tale ricerca produce dei risultati interessanti:

> *Vitello gentile*, che ha quattro anni ed è fuor di dentini
>
> Dal [*Vocabolario milanese-italiano*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=3uY3AQAAMAAJ&lpg=PA482&ots=Q8WEVEWoWV&dq=%22vitello%20gentile%22&pg=PA482#v=onepage&q=%22vitello%20gentile%22&f=false) di Francesco Cherubini

Sembra probabile quindi che un *macello gentile* indicasse, nel nord ovest italiano, un macello specializzato nella carne di vitello, più cara ma di qualità superiore rispetto alle altre carni.

Comment: Ho trovato anche [questa spiegazione](https://books.google.es/books?id=49ehbrNQcTEC&pg=PA20&dq=%22Macello+gentile%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwij5LuT4vjbAhVEU1AKHWawB38Q6AEIGjAD#v=onepage&q=%22Macello%20gentile%22&f=false) in un libro dell'Ottocento: «A Torino, le parole *Macello gentile* significano macello di buoi, a distinzione di quelli di giovenche.»

Answer (score 1):

Inoltre ai documenti citati da Denis Nardin nella sua risposta, il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI09/00000375.jpg) riporta questa citazione dal *Dizionario moderno delle parole che non si trovano nei dizionari comuni* con  un *Proemio* di  A. Schiaffini  e  con un'*Appendice* di ottomila voci
nuovamente  compilata  da  B. Migliorini, Milano, 1950 (1ª edizione originale, 1905):

> *Panzini*, IV-390:  ‘ Macello  gentile ’:  dove 
>   si  vende  ‘ carne  fine ’  di  vitello (Piemonte). Che razza di espressione!